# Invisible Physics to Certain Objects in the BGE

Tags: game-engine, physics

I'm making a first person view game.  I have an invisible collision body that I use for interaction with other objects.  I have it so that the player can "shoot" cubes.  How ever, if the player looks down and tries to shoot (for example if an enemy is coming close) the bullet gets bounced off the collision body for the character.  Is it possible to make it so that my bullets can collide with everything except for the collision body?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with collision mask and collision group.

[image]

These options are found in the physics panel. To fix your particular problem, select the invisible collision box for the player and put it in collision group 2.

Next, select the bullet and while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> click on the 2nd box in collision mask. This will stop the bullet from colliding with anything in collision group/layer 2.